# Strange behavior displaying matrix opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to implement the Bayer Color Filter Array in OpenCV!

Here's the code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  int rows = 4, cols = 4;

  cv::Mat_<uchar> mask(rows, cols);

  cv::Mat_<uchar> pattern(1, cols);

  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i = i + 2) pattern(0, i) = 1;

  for (int j = 0; j < rows; j = j + 2) pattern.row(0).copyTo(mask.row(j));

  cout << mask << endl;

  namedWindow( "Result" );
  imshow( "Result", mask );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I comment the lines 23 to 26, the output in the statement of the line 21 is as I expect.

```
[1, 0, 1, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0;
  1, 0, 1, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0]
```

but when the lines are uncommented, the output become something like that:

```
[1, 100, 1, 48;
  47, 117, 115, 98;
  1, 100, 1, 48;
  49, 47, 50, 45]
```

I don't understand what's wrong. I'm printing the values before the commented lines, but somehow it seems they are affecting the matrix from the start.

Comment: there are no line numbers, so tell us please which lines cause your problems. Are you linking the right libraries (debug libraries for debug build or release libs for release build) (especially highgui lib)?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot the lines =P

Comment: 'namedWindow( "Result" );
  imshow( "Result", mask );

  waitKey(0);'

Comment: did you check which libraries you linked? (e.g. whether it is `opencv_core249.lib` and `opencv_highgui249.lib` or `opencv_core249d.lib` and `opencv_highgui249d.lib`)

Comment: Thanks for the support @Micka... Yes, they are all in the library path!

Comment: but which one did you link?

Comment: As I'm working on a linux enviroment, I've linked the libs __opencv_core.so__, __opencv_higui.so__ and __opencv_imgproc.so__ in the __Release__ configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using uninitialized values. Without the namedWindow and imshow stuff you were just lucky.

Try:

```
using namespace cv;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  int rows = 4, cols = 4;

  cv::Mat_<uchar> mask(rows, cols);

  cv::Mat_<uchar> pattern(1, cols);

  // ------------------------------------------
  // initialize your matrices:
  for(int j=0; j<rows; ++j)
      for(int i=0; i<cols; ++i)
      {
          mask(j,i) = 0;
      }
  for(int i=0; i<cols; ++i) pattern(0,i) = 0;
  // ------------------------------------------


  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i = i + 2) pattern(0, i) = 1;

  for (int j = 0; j < rows; j = j + 2) pattern.row(0).copyTo(mask.row(j));

  cout << mask << endl;

  namedWindow( "Result" );
  imshow( "Result", mask );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man =D My mistake. Actually I'm specifying now the values of the elements in the constructor of the Mats, but its the same thing. Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!